# How to copy first line of text file to start or end of all another lines?

Tags: notepad++, regex, awk, text-editing

I am currently editing down multiple large text files (maybe 500 different text files) , and need to copy first line of text files to start or end of all another lines
For example this is one of my text files:

```
1996
word
character
word2
character2
browser
website
```

Now i want to copy first line to first of another lines:

```
1996,word
1996,character
1996,word2
1996,character2
1996,browser
1996,website
```

Note: 1) Each file has a different number of lines 2) The first line of each file is not the same and may contain the year or the year plus the month name (Example: 2000 April or 2005 march) 3) after copy first line to start of all, first line should remove 4) first line should separator by semicolon from other content of lines

Now which script or regex can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this purpose:

```
awk '{if (NR==1) a=$0 ; else print a","$0}' input_file
```

because `a` variable get entire row 1 there can be any text.

```
[romeo@rhel01 tmp]$ cat qq
1996 May
word
character
word2
character2
browser
website
[romeo@rhel01 tmp]$  awk '{if (NR==1) a=$0 ; else print a","$0}' qq
1996 May,word
1996 May,character
1996 May,word2
1996 May,character2
1996 May,browser
1996 May,website
```